# Estimate of the speed of convergence to normal of the average of binomially distributioned variables

Tags: probability, statistics

Let us fix $n$, and consider a sequence of identical, independent random variables with binomial distributions with $n$ trials and probability of success $p=1/2$. Are there estimate on how fast the average of the sequence will converge to a normal distribution? (I mean, more accurate than application of the standard results.)

Comment: Is the standard result the Berry–Esseen theorem?

Comment: Yes.  There are also a few improvements around,  but with a symmetric binomial convergence should be really faster. It is the original case proved by De Moivre almost 300 years ago, BTW.

Comment: It will only be *faster* (than what?) by a constant - which I do not think really counts

Comment: Actually in my case better constants are interesting.

Comment: If you want faster convergence, try a continuous uniform random variable on an interval

Answer (score 2):

If $X_i$ are $\text{Bin}(n, \frac12)$ then each has mean $\frac{n}{2}$ and variance  $\frac{n}{4}$

If you take $m$ i.i.d. samples of this binomial random variable then their sum $m\overline{X}$ is binomially distributed with parameters $mn$ and $\frac12$, with the consequence that $\overline{X}$ has mean $\frac{n}{2}$ and variance  $\frac{n}{4m}$.

Consider the error in using a normal approximation to find $\Pr(\overline{X}\lt \frac{n}{2})$ or $\Pr(\overline{X}\le \frac{n}{2})$.  The approximation will suggest $\frac12$ for each, but if $nm$ is even then each will be wrong by $\frac12{nm \choose nm/2}2^{-nm}$, which by Stirling's approximation to the factorial, this error will be about $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi nm}}$

For example if $n=10$ and $m=100$,  then the two probabilities are actually about $0.4873875$ and $0.5126125$ while $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi nm}} \approx 0.0126157$

The error being proportionate to $\frac{1}{\sqrt{m}}$ is consistent with the Berry–Esseen theorem, showing that you do not get *faster* convergence

Comment: If you want really faster convergence, try starting with a random variable with a uniform distribution on an interval.

Comment: Actually, the error bound is *exactly* $1/\sqrt{2\pi m}$:

https://epubs.siam.org/doi/abs/10.1137/S0040585X97983213

Comment: @seba That link is for $m$ Bernoulli$\left(\frac12\right)$ random variables.  Here you have $m$ Binomial$\left(n,\frac12\right)$ random variables, which apart from scaling corresponds to $1$  Binomial$\left(nm,\frac12\right)$ random variable or to $nm$ Bernoulli$\left(\frac12\right)$ random variables, and hence an error of $1/\sqrt{2\pi nm}$

Comment: I know.  I took out the $n$ from the picture as you did ("proportionate to $1/\sqrt m$").